# printer driver for konica minolta pagepro 1490mf

Tags: drivers, printing

I bought a laser printer Konica PagePro 1490 MF, but I can not find the drivers.
can anyone help me?
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: I followed the instructions and installed the driver from the vendors website.
Now the printer is responding (I hear a noise from the printer as soon as I send a print request) but at the end nothing is printed.
Does anyone has a clue what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

The linux printer driver for your printer can be downloaded from the [vendors website](http://www.konicaminolta.eu/business-solutions/support/download-center.html?product=101488&resulttype=drivers&legacy=1&optiondocuments=0&productgroup=2&page=1&targetOption=product) i.e. choose from the operating system drop-down list "linux"

Open the zip file using Archive Manager.

If you navigate through the extracted files you'll see some Ubuntu installation instructions.